# Python Tkinter Attribute Error When Using Two Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi there in my code I'm am getting an the error `AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'calculate_button'` And I don't know why its not working when I am using two classes. Also I don't want to make the class inherit each other nor make it an object.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class Logic:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    as_meter = dict(mm=0.001, cm=0.01, inch=0.0254,ft=0.3048, yd=0.9144, m=1.0,km=1000.0, mi=1609.344,)
    def calculate(self, *args):
        try:
            v = float(c)
        except ValueError:
            self.d.set('Invalid Input')
            return
        m = v * sign * self.as_meter [self.a]
        r = m/self.as_meter[self.b]
        answer = (self.d.set("{:.5g}".format(r)))
        return answer

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.notebook.pack()

        self.length_frame = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.length_frame, text = 'Length')

        #Combobox
        self.measurements = StringVar()
        self.Combobox_Length_Left = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements, values = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state=['readonly'])
        self.Combobox_Length_Left.current(5)
        self.Combobox_Length_Left.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        self.measurements1 = StringVar()
        self.Combobox_Length_Right = ttk.Combobox(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.measurements1, value = ('mm', 'cm', 'inch', 'ft', 'yd', 'm', 'km', 'mi'), width = 10,state = ['readonly'])
        self.Combobox_Length_Right.current(5)
        self.Combobox_Length_Right.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        #Labels
        self.Conversion = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'Convertion:').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        self.Label_Blank = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = '').grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        self.Label_To2 = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)
        self.Label_To = ttk.Label(self.length_frame, text = 'to').grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = E)

        #Entry Boxes
        self.Text_Length_Left = StringVar()
        self.Entry_Length_Left = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Left,width = 13)
        self.Entry_Length_Left.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        self.Text_Length_Right = StringVar()
        self.Entry_Length_Right = ttk.Entry(self.length_frame, textvariable = self.Text_Length_Right,width = 13, state='readonly')
        self.Entry_Length_Right.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        def calculate_button(self):
            c_l = self.measurements.get()
            c_r = self.measurements1.get()
            e_l = self.Text_Length_Left.get()
            e_r = self.Text_Length_Right.get()

            c = Logic(c_l,c_r,e_l,e_r)

            self.Text_Length_Right.set('')
            self.Text_Length_Right.set(c.calulate())

        #Button
        self.Convert_Button = ttk.Button(self.length_frame, text = 'Convert',command = calculate_button, width = 10).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = S)









def main():
root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.title('Metric Calculator')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

main()

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the self.convert_button, remove the parenthesis from self.calculate_button(). Keep it just self.calculate_button

Comment: Yeah I have tried that and I still get the same error.

Comment: the `def calculate_button(self):` is indented into the `__init__` method instead of the class, just de-dent the code so it is in the right spot.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues with your code:

1. As @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen commented you, `calculate_button()` is wrongly intended and does not belong to `GUI()` class
2. As @MotKohn answered, you must remove `()` from `calculate_button()` in `Convert_Button` button.
3. `Logic()` is not  defined neither in `GUI()` nor in `Converversion()` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the help man! Really appreciate it! But now im getting the error! `TypeError: calculate_button() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'self', 'c_l', 'c_r', 'e_l', and 'e_r'`

Comment: What is `sign` in `calculate()`? It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: don't you mean `self`

Comment: No, I mean `sign` in this line of code: `m = v * sign * self.as_meter [self.a]`

Comment: Hi even if you remove `sign` I still get the error `TypeError: calculate_button() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'self', 'c_l', 'c_r', 'e_l', and 'e_r'`

Answer (score 1):

unindent `calculate_button` 1 level. It should not be a function in the **init** function rather a function of the class **GUI**. Remove `()` as mentioned in comment.

There is still a bug,

> NameError: name 'Logic' is not defined

Comment: Yeah I have done that but I got the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'calculate_button' referenced before assignment` here is a picture  https://gyazo.com/a2785666ce624ff85f8e4f1cdafb39c9